# Why this regular expression isn't matching this string?

Tags: c++

I have the next code sample:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    regex third("([a-zA-Z]*) ([a-zA-Z]*)[\s]*([a-zA-Z]*)");
    smatch third_match;
    getline(cin, input);
    while (input != "q")
    {
        if(regex_match(input, third_match, third))
            cout << "Ok" << endl;
        getline(cin, input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter a string, say:

"I am_____________happy" (alot of spaces instead of the underscore ('_').

Then it should work- because I have a "word" and then a "space" and then a "word" and then "how many spaces that I want, and then a "word", and this should match my expression above, but is doesnt. 
Why?

Comment: is your input function capturing the end-of-line character?

Comment: Your I/O code is bad. It goes into an infinite loop generically because it fails to check the result of the I/O operation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
regex third("([a-zA-Z]*) ([a-zA-Z]*)[\\s]*([a-zA-Z]*)");
//                                  ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

because you used `regex_match` and instead you should use `regex_search`
**match** will be true if the entire mach exactly find
**serach** will be true if at least one match find
Also all escape characters should be `\\`